# New Pandas Product/Sum Logic

Tags: python, pandas, math

After the release of `pandas 0.22.0` there was a signigicant change to `sum()` and `product()` which is talked about in the [What's New Section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html). I was talking this over with some <s>math nerds</s> Mathematicians and this has some big implications! I was wondering *why* this change was made. Was this simply for the explanations given for Resampling, Grouping, etc? It seems like `NaN` is now treated like an [identity element.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element)

In *basic* math terms an [Identity Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) always returns the same value that was passed through it. Think `x=y` or `1 + 0 = 1` or `2 * 1 = 2`. 0 is the identity element for addition (`x+0` will return `x`), whereas 1 is the identity element for multiplication (`x*1` will return `x`).

Testing below:

```
0.20.2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': [3,2,3], 'nans':[3,np.NaN,np.NaN]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'test': [3,2,3], 'nans':[np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]}) 

df.prod()            df2.prod()  
nans     3.0         nans    NaN 
test    18.0         test    18.0  

df.sum()             df2.sum()
nans    3.0          nans    NaN 
test    8.0          test    8.0

#----------------------------------------------------

'0.22.0'

df.prod()            df2.prod()
nans     3.0         nans    1.0
test    18.0         test    18.0

df.sum()             df2.sum()
nans    3.0          nans    0.0
test    8.0          test    8.0
```

Notice that the left most examples for `df` remain the same. however `df2` changes. Is this change due to my hypothesis of `NaNs` being treated as identity elements? Or is this a [Red Herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)? Does anybody have any documentation or further explanation of *why* this change occurred?

Comment: Very good point. In my case this change in pandas resulted in an error that actually caused me to have wrong results because my code relied on this functionality. Yeah I know I should have read the release notes, but honestly, this is a headache.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the discussion of the change here.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9422

Comment: interesting. this discussion seems to be going back to 2015. However the end of the thread doesn't really provide the end reasoning.